# Passing the methods hide/show to another method

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, methods

I am calling an object method in two ways in my code:

`this.reveal.updateVisuals(i, 'show')`;

or

```
this.reveal.updateVisuals(i, 'hide');
```

and I am passing the hide and show condition as a string, to be later evaluated and used as a method. Please note the condition: if (effect === 'show/hide').

```
 updateVisuals: function (time, effect) {
      // Check if parameter exists and property can be read
      if (this.breakpointsMap && typeof this.breakpointsMap[checkTime] !== "undefined") {
        if (effect === 'show') {
          // display the items that were fast forwarded
          var k = this.breakpointsMap[checkTime].length;
          while (k--) {
            try {
              this.breakpointsMap[checkTime][k].show();
            } catch (err) {}
          }
        } else if (effect === 'hide') {
          // display the items that were fast forwarded
          var k = this.breakpointsMap[checkTime].length;
          while (k--) {
            try {
              this.breakpointsMap[checkTime][k].hide();
            } catch (err) {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

However the code seems duplicated and I was wondering if there is a way to pass hide or show as a method to the method and apply it on the array, when needed. I tried something like this:

this.reveal.updateVisuals(i).show

Comment: You can use something like this `this.breakpointsMap[checkTime][k][effect]();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a method property by it's (string) name using [bracket] notation.

```
updateVisuals: function (time, effect) {
  // Check if parameter exists and property can be read
  if (this.breakpointsMap && typeof this.breakpointsMap[checkTime] !== "undefined") {
    var k = this.breakpointsMap[checkTime].length;
    while (k--) {
      try {
        this.breakpointsMap[checkTime][k][effect]();
      } catch (err) {}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways you can use to simplify this, here are a couple:

```
updateVisuals: function (time, effect) {
  if (this.breakpointsMap && typeof this.breakpointsMap[checkTime] !== "undefined") {
      this.breakpointsMap[checkTime].forEach(e => e[effect]());
  }
}
```

Or returning the array:

```
updateVisuals: function (time, effect) {
  if (this.breakpointsMap && typeof this.breakpointsMap[checkTime] !== "undefined") {
      return this.breakpointsMap[checkTime];
  }else{
      return [];
  }
}

this.reveal.updateVisuals(i).forEach(e => e.show());
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Es6, you can do:

```
    function updateVisuals  (time, effect) {
    // Check if parameter exists and property can be read
        if (this.breakpointsMap && typeof this.breakpointsMap[checkTime] !== "undefined") {
            let execFn= (arrindex) => breakpointsMap[checkTime][arrindex].show();
            if (effect === 'hide') 
            { 
                execFn = (arrindex) => breakpointsMap[checkTime][arrindex].hide();
            }     
                // display the items that were fast forwarded
                var k = this.breakpointsMap[checkTime].length;
                while (k--) {
                try {
                    execFn(k);
                } catch (err) {}
            }
        }
    }
```

I assume that var checkTime is global or in closure. If you are using version lower tan es6 you can use execFn= function (arrindex) {...}, a then bind this argument when calling method after.